# Data Domain Boost viewing backups

Tags: t-sql, backup

Does anyone have any insight on how to view backups in Data Domain? Preferably with T-SQL. Thanks in advance.

Found the following T-SQL statement in EMC's documentation but I'm receiving the following error when using the correct "Client":

T_SQL Statement_______________________

```
USE [master]
GO
DECLARE @returnCode int
EXEC @returnCode = dbo.emc_run_delete ' -b "2 months ago" -e
"now" -N mssql -a "DDBOOST_USER=user" -a
"DEVICE_PATH=/path" -a "DEVICE_HOST=host" -a
"CLIENT=name"'
IF @returnCode <> 0
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Fail!', 16, 1)
END
```

Error______________________

```
4690:ddbmexptool:The name 'CLIENT' does not correspond to a valid LNM parameter.
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Fail!
```

Answer (score 1):

For client parameter, please mention the database server name along with FQDN.

For example if your server name is test and domain is abc.com, then enter the value for Client as "test.abc.com".

Also, please execute the statement  in one Line without any Returns/space:

```
EXEC @returnCode = dbo.emc_run_delete ' -b "2 months ago" -e
"now" -N mssql -a "DDBOOST_USER=user" -a
"DEVICE_PATH=/path" -a "DEVICE_HOST=host" -a
"CLIENT=test.abc.com"'
```